# mergBanner won't allow save as standalone in Livecode 8

Tags: ios, livecode

I had the mergBanner extension working fine until I upgraded to Livecode 8. Now it won't let me save my app as a standalone unless I delete the copy file and associated code.

Do I need to download mergbanner2 or is it likely to be something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveCode externals are compiled against multiple iOS SDKs and the LiveCode standalone builder will pick the right binary to use depending on which iOS SDK you are building against. mergBanner 1 has not been compiled against the full range of SDKs that available in LiveCode 8 so yes in order to use mergBanner with newer versions of Xcode & LiveCode you will need to upgrade to the new version.